# Selecting cell values from tablebased on checkbox checked property

Tags: jquery, html, razor

I have a html table and I am trying to form a list with the values from the second column (where the checkbox is checked in the first column).

I have tried many approaches using jQuery, but nothing works.

HTML

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
         <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
         <td>12</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td>13</td>
    </tr>

 </table>

 <input id="submit-btn" type="button" style="submit-btn" >
```

jQuery

```
values =[];

$("#submit-btn").click(function() {
    $('#table1 tr').each(function () {
        row = $(this);

        if(row.children('td:eq(0) > checkbox').prop('checked'))
        {
            values.push(row.children('td:eq(1)').text());
            console.log(values);
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Side note: Your code is falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog). Be sure to declare your variables.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing this out to me.I am a beginner to javascript.I find it quite awkward and new all this DOM manipulation (coming from C++/C#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`:checked` pseudo-selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) to find all checked checkboxes in the table, then use `closest` to go up to the `td` they're in, `next` to move to the next `td`, and `text` to get that `td`'s text:

```
$("#table1 input:checked").each(function() {
    values.push($(this).closest("td").next().text());
});
```

Live Example:

```js
$("#submit-btn").click(function() {
  var values = [];
  $("#table1 input:checked").each(function() {
    values.push($(this).closest("td").next().text());
  });
  console.log(values);
});
```

```html
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>

</table>

<input id="submit-btn" type="button" style="submit-btn">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Your approach didn't work for two reasons:

- `td:eq(0) > checkbox` looks for a `<td><checkbox ..>` element. The tag is `input` (specifically, it's a `input[type=checkbox]`), not `checkbox`.
- Once you fix that, no *children* of the `tr` element match `td:eq(0) > input[type=checkbox]`, so `row.children("td:eq(0) > input[type=checkbox]")` returns an empty set. The checkboxes aren't *children* of the row, the `td`s are. (The checkboxes are *descendants*, but not children.)

Your approach would work if you fixed both of those issues:

```js
$("#submit-btn").click(function() {
  var values = [];
  $('#table1 tr').each(function() {
    var row = $(this);
    if (row.find('td:eq(0) > input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked')) {
      values.push(row.children('td:eq(1)').text());
    }
  });
  console.log(values);
});
```

```html
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>

</table>

<input id="submit-btn" type="button" style="submit-btn">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...but using `:checked` leaves more of the work to jQuery's optimized code.

Comment: Thank you very much sir for the explanation ! It worked like a charm.